# Website Audio Stops Loading

Tags: html, audio, mp3, loading, mediaelement

I am in desperate need of help here... I have a site that I made for my church and we have entire lessons you can listen to.  Here is an example:

http://tetelestai.org/media/audio/default.html?series=the_4th_g&lesson=the_4th_g_296&part=&properName=The%204th%20G&lessonNum=296&lessonName=Lesson%20296&date=&verses=

The problem is that the lessons stop buffering after a few minutes.  I have done a lot of troubleshooting here and have found that the problem is not with the audio player (I have implemented several different jQuery, HTML5, and Flash players to try and overcome the issue.  It's also not the files themselves... they all work end-to-end when I play them locally.

Also, most of the lessons worked perfectly before I launched the site.

So my only conclusion is that it has to be something to do with how the file is loading into the site... and something is telling it to stop loading.

I have also, by the way, tried to get rid of the dynamic generation of the audio player and made it an absolute reference... that didn't work either.

Anyway, here is the code... I could really, *really* use some help here:

```
//Header
<code><script src="../../mediaelement/build/jquery.js"></script>
```

```
//Body
<div id="aud">
                    <audio controls="control" preload="none" src="../../assets/audio/the_4th_g/the_4th_g_296.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
                </div>

                <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $('#version').html( mejs.version);

                    // declare audio player with jQuery
                    $('audio').mediaelementplayer({audioWidth: 380, success: function(me) {  $('#audio-type').html( me.pluginType); }});


                });
                </script>
```

Note: the code I have listed is my most recent code and is different from what is in the link.

Comment: How large are these mp3 files? It could be related to it being seved from apache on a GoDaddy shared server.

Comment: On average, they are around 30MB.  So are you suggesting that I would have to go to a dedicated server to resolve the issue, or is there something I can do in the apache setup to change bandwidth constraints?

Comment: I see a 206 Partial Content come down that's pretty large (takes about 1.3 minutes to download just that portion) and the mp3 itself never loads. I'm really thinking the GoDaddy server just doesn't like streaming these files. It's taking me literally 10 minutes to download the 76MB file you linked to.
As an experiment, try uploading the file to a Google Drive and make it a public share and see if serving them from there solves the issue.

Comment: Yeah, so that's my biggest audio file.  I uploaded the file with public sharing to google docs (https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6WNAOzoOIOEejBvV29BTldTaUU) and put it as an absolute reference in a staging audio site, but it's not loading at all.  Here is the code: <audio controls="control" preload="none" src="https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6WNAOzoOIOEejBvV29BTldTaUU" type="audio/mp3" /> Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.
Try hosted links: https://googledrive.com/host/0B6WNAOzoOIOEejBvV29BTldTaUU

Google Drive lets you use it like a little CDN. Take the id value from that link and stick it at the end of "https://googledrive.com/host/" and it should serve.

Comment: @oliverseal - thanks so much for helping btw... it looks like you're right... the google link is working the whole way through... So what is the solution here?  It's not feasible for me to upload thousands of audio and video lessons to google drive and that's part of what I'm paying GoDaddy for... should I just call them and have them figure it out?

Comment: I'm not sure what type of account you have with GoDaddy, but they're generally the worst option for anything other than the simplest of sites. The account the site is on may not support large file downloads -- it might cap at ~10MB. (Purely conjecture.) Give them a call. I suspect they'll just try to sell you something, though. :)

While I understand your point about paying GoDaddy for the service, I will point out that it _is_ fairly common to host files like this in a separate CDN or static server on the modern web.